# Determine if an element was clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

How can I determine if an element was clicked with jQuery?

Something like `$('.ele').is(':clicked');`

I am stuck with jQuery 1.7.2, and what I am trying to do is force the closing of some modal elements, when anywhere in the document is clicked and one is already open.

So I've got:

```
$('body').on('click', function () {
    if ($('.calc-info').is(':visible') && !$('.mi').is(':clicked')) {
        $('.calc-info').fadeOut('fast');
    }
});
```

but it throws an error, because there is no `:clicked` expression

## Notes

- `.calc-info` is the modal
- `.mi` is the button to click to open said modal

Comment: Do you mean directly clicked? What if its descendants were clicked. Should that count?

Comment: `.mi` has no decendants, it's an image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it the other way around, check if the clicked element (the event.target) matches a selector

```
$('body').on('click', function (event) {
    if ( $(event.target).is('.ele') ) {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

In your case I'd go with

```
$('body').on('click', function (event) {
    if ( $('.calc-info').is(':visible') && 
         !($(event.target).closest('.mi').length)
       ) {
          $('.calc-info').fadeOut('fast');
    }
});
```

Comment: @o7thWebDesign It will work but if you have some other elements inside .ele. That will not work. So you have to check for the ancestor nodes too.

Comment: as my comment under the question states...  "`.mi` (which is `.ele`) has no decendants, it's an image"

Comment: Then that's all you need, no need for closest() if it's an image, or any other element without children.

Comment: agreed.   Won't let me accept though... states I have to wait 4 more minutes :)

Comment: Then you just have to wait, there's a timer to give people a chance to answer before the OP accepts.

Answer (score 1):

Just check whether the clicked `element` is having the `class` that is to be excluded. and its just a kind of `short circuit` implementation. The following code will block the unnecessary `dom traversal` if user directly clicks on the target element.

Try this,

```
$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    if ($('.calc-info').is(':visible') 
    && !$(e.target).hasClass('mi') 
    && !$(e.target).parents('.mi').length) {

        $('.calc-info').fadeOut('fast');

    }
});
```

Comment: wasn't me, but `e` is the event, it can't have a class

Comment: @adeneo Thanks. Actually that was a typo. I just corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
$('mi').on('click', function () {
$('mi').attr('rel',"clicked");
});
$('body').on('click', function () {
if ($('.calc-info').is(':visible') && !$('.mi').attr('rel')=='clicked') {
    $('.calc-info').fadeOut('fast');
}
});`
```